# Regex should capture links and convert to HTML but not already HTML links

Tags: javascript, html, regex

What I want to do is

When having such a text `This is a link: https://website.com hahaha` it should turn it into

`This is a link:  <a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">https://website.com</a> hahaha`

but when I have

`This is a link: <a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">https://website.com</a> hahaha` it should not do anything.

Currently, I have this function

```
static linkify(inputText: string): string {
    // URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    const replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
    let replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>')

    // URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    const replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>')

    // Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    const replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>')

    return replacedText
}
```

When I input
`<a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">https://website.com</a>`
it gives me
`<a href="<a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">https://website.com</a>" target="_blank"><a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">https://website.com</a></a>`

replacing all `https://website.com` with `<a href="https://website.com" target="_blank">https://website.com</a>`

How can I not make it replace those?

Thanks

Comment: so why don't you add a regex to check if the inputText is already an HTML element, and if that's the case return it without any modifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here should work, sample text provided to test various scenarios:

```js
function linkify(text) {
  // turn standalone www. into a URL:
  const wwwRegex = /(?<![\/'">])(www\.)/gm;
  // turn URL into link:
  const urlRegex = /(?<!['">])((https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
  // turn email into link:
  const emailRegex = /(?<!['">])(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gm;
  text = text
    .replace(wwwRegex, 'http:\/\/$1')
    .replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>')
    .replace(emailRegex, '<a href="mailto:$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
  return text;
}

const text = 'Sample text with https://google.com, and https://www.google.com/search?q=regex. Sometimes just www.google.com, and keep <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">https://www.google.com</a> as is. Email jimmy.neutron@gmail.com should work as well. One more <a href="www.mylink.com">Link</a> test. No protocol link <a href="www.mylink.com" target="_blank">www.mylink.com</a>.';

var result = linkify(text);
console.log(result);
```

Output: (newlines added for clarity)

```
Sample text with <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">https://google.com</a>, 
and <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=regex" target="_blank">https://www.google.com/search?q=regex</a>. 
Sometimes just <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">http://www.google.com</a>, 
and keep <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">https://www.google.com</a> 
as is. Email 
<a href="mailto:jimmy.neutron@gmail.com" target="_blank">jimmy.neutron@gmail.com</a> 
should work as well.
One more <a href="http://www.mylink.com">Link</a> test.
No protocol link <a href="www.mylink.com" target="_blank">www.mylink.com</a>.
```

Explanation wwwRegex:

- turn standalone `www.` into a URL, will be linked later:
- `/(?<![\/'">])(www\.)/` - negative lookbehind for a `/`, followed by `www.` (captured)
- in case your regex engine does not support negative lookbehind use:
- `/(^|[^\/'">])(www\.)/` - capture a non-`/` (if any), reference as `$1`

Explanation urlRegex:

- turn URL into link:
- `/(?<!['">])((https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/` - negative lookbehind for a `'`, `"`, or `>`, followed by a URL pattern (captured)

Explanation emailRegex:

- turn email into link:
- `/(?<!['">])(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/` - negative lookbehind for a `'`, `"`, or `>`, followed by an email pattern (captured)

Comment: It forces the link to change if I add this: `<a href="www.mylink.com">Link</a>` it turns the result to `<a href="http://www.mylink.com" target="_blank">http://www.mylink.com</a>` which is not ideal. It should not be doing anything to it. I think these tests give some insight: https://prnt.sc/waanuq

Comment: @demiculus: No it does not. I updated the test input, and your `<a href="www.mylink.com">Link</a>` is not changed. Please verify by running the code snippet.

Comment: When I put this `<a href="www.mylink.com" target="_blank">www.mylink.com</a>` it changes it to `<a href="http://www.mylink.com" target="_blank">http://www.mylink.com</a>` wheres it shouldn't change any <a> tag at all

Comment: You can achieve this by simply tweaking the `wwwRegx`. Run the code snipped again, I added your example.

Comment: Cool, though this doesn't work on Safari :/

Comment: Since it uses look behind assertions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Please see my note "in case your regex engine does not support negative lookbehind use"